# Trying to delay a jQuery post

Tags: jquery, post, loops, delay

I have this post code inside a loop (while i<10) and I am trying to delay each post for 5 sec but instead what is doing is delaying 5 sec and sends all 10 posts at once

Is there a way to do interval or delay each post in jQuery or Ajax inside a loop?

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
                setTimeout(function(){
            $.post("Trigger.aspx", { phone: phoneval,
            sms: smsval }, function(data) {
                $('.result').html(data);
            });
            },5000);
            return false;
    });
```

Comment: What's the point of sending the same request 10 times separated by 5 seconds?

Answer (score 1):

as far as i remember jquery's ajax call has a beforeSend function that maybe addressed your problem

Answer (score 1):

Simply use an increasing delay:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        setTimeout(function(){
            $.post("Trigger.aspx", {
                phone: phoneval,
                sms: smsval
            }, function(data) {
                $('.result').html(data);
            });
        }, 5000 * i);
    }
});
```

If the first POST should be delayed by 5 seconds, use `5000 * (i + 1)` or change your loop to `for(var i = 1; i <= 10; i++)`.

Comment: Tried that and the delay works fine but I want to change the phoneval and smsval every loop count.

Comment: var phoneval = "<%=(varmin.Fields.Item("phone").Value)%>" 
    var smsval = "<%=checkinactive.Fields.Item("audio").Value%>"

Comment: and used   for(;!varmin.atEnd(); varmin.moveNext())    which does not delay at all.

Comment: If the various phoneval/smsval values come from a serverside script which seems to be the case you need to create a JavaScript array with them. Then you can simply use `phoneval[i]` and `smsval[i]`